# Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress. On Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-server

Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress

I tried to fix this problem by making sure MySQL server is running.

```
/etc/init.d/mysql status
```

I found it is running properly.

Then I cheked for MySQL Module for php5 is installed

```
dpkg --list | grep php5-mysql
```

and finally, I restarted the NGINX:

```
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Still facing the same issue again and again:

**Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.**

Comment: restarted nginx with apache2 restart??

Comment: PHP5.5.

I didn't restart apache2

Comment: Try `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: did it number of times.

Still facing the same issue

Comment: Are you running both Apache and Nginx?  Which is serving WordPress?

Comment: @thunderblaster Only running nginx and nginx is serving WordPress.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for contributing to the answer.

Nothing worked to solve this issue. Although I faced the same issue. @igor yavych answer was quite useful.

Finally R&D worked and here's the final solution:

In order to deploy PHP applications, you will need to implement the following “PHP-FastCGI” solution to allow nginx to properly handle and serve pages that contain PHP code.

```
sudo apt-get install php5-cli php5-cgi php5-fpm
```

Now, install NGINX:

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
```

Now configure NGINX then restart NGINX and PHP5-fpm:

```
service php5-fpm restart
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

Issue the following command to install the MySQL server packages and required PHP support for MySQL (You do not have to purge MySQL Server):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server php5-mysql
```

Finally restart php5-fpm:

```
service php5-fpm restart
```

Congratulations! Now it's working!

You can also check my [step-by-step guide](https://www.websitevidya.com/php-installation-appears-missing-mysql-extension-required-wordpress/).

Answer (score 1):

This is error that means that your PHP either has mysql/mysqli extension disabled or doesn't have it to begin with. If said extension is actually present, check your `php.ini` and your additional configuration files to see if it's actually enabled (for example `extension=/path/to/extension/mysql.so`). You can also check `phpinfo` to see what's actually there.

Comment: Still facing the same issue:
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Fixing this problem was quite simple. All I had to do is go into my nginx server block like so:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/myblog.com
```

then in the server block all I had to do is find

```
php7.0
```

and change it to

```
php7.2
```

Basically, with the upgrade of Ubunto 17.04 to 17.10 php7.0 was no longer working but I still had php7.0.

this is where you will find it in your server block:

```
  fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
```

So, from now on just remember to update your nginx server blocks after an upgrade of Ubuntu or PHP. There is no need to mess with the shell or other configurations any further.